# What is the intuitive meaning of a determinant?

Tags: determinant, intuition

I know how to calculate a determinant, but I wanted to know what the meaning of a determinant is? So how could I explain to a child, what a determinant actually is.

Could I think of it as a measure of independence of the columns or rows? Or is there another interpretation that is even simpler?

Edit: The explanation should also explain, the role of the determinant for the solvability of linear equations.

Comment: Unless the child is already interested in determinants, there is no reason to explain them to her.

Comment: @GEdgar, (+1) such a great answer! Loved it :))

Answer (score 12):

The determinant is the volume of parallelepiped formed by the vectors.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) is more precise:

> Determinants express the signed $n$-dimensional volumes of $n$-dimensional parallelepipeds.

The determinant is zero iff the vectors are linearly dependent. In this sense, it is a coarse measure of the independence of vectors.

The finer measure of independence of the columns or rows is the [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)).

A system of linear equations $Ax=b$ is solvable iff $rank(A)=rank(A\mid b)$, where $A\mid b$ is the [augmented matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix).

Determinants appear in the actual solution of systems of linear equations via [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule)  (but this is mainly an important theoretical result, because it is not pratical, except for very small systems).

Comment: I like this, but it seems hard for me to connect this to solving linear equastions. Why should the volume have something to do with the solvability of a system. Still a nice interpretation.

Answer (score 7):

Adding to lhf's answer, you can think of the 'geometric' meaning of this volume interpretation: think of how $A$ acts on the vector space $V$.

The volume of the parallelepiped is connected to this interpretation in that the parallelepiped is the image under $A$ of the unit cube. In other words, the parallelepiped is a small-scale model of how $A$ acts on the whole of $V$ (because of linearity!).

When the volume is $0$, it means one or more dimensions were lost in the transfomation (the 'area' of a line or the 'three dimensional volume' of a plane are both zero). This means that, for $Ax = b$, some vectors $b$ – those that have a component in the 'lost dimensions' – won't be reachable at all, while any others will admit multiple solutions (because adding to $x$ some $u$ that lies in those dimensions that are discarded by $A$ does not change the result).

Answer (score 2):

I think @lhf 's answer is the best intuitive explanation.

In response to your edit: a system of $n$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns will always have a unique solution if and only if the determinant is not $0$, because that is the condition that says the rank is $n$ so the corresponding linear map is one to one and onto. But in practice you don't use determinants to solve the equations - although students find it cool, [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule) is really only of theoretical interest. Gaussian elimination (and more advanced numerical methods) do the job better, and give you more information - even when the determinant is $0$ the equation will sometimes have solutions, and when it does they won't be unique.

Answer (score 1):

The intuition I have stuck with once I discovered it is the following. Let $f(x) = Ax$ be a linear transform where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. Then the determinant $|A|$ is the *volume scaling factor* of the transform $f$.  That is, if $S$ is a set in $n$-space that has volume $V$, then $f(S)$ is a set in $n$-space that has volume $V \cdot |A|$.